# Vim Ignores Aliases

Tags: shell, vim, alias, ignore

If I map a command in vim using something like

```
map <f4> :! pdflatex %<cr>
```

Vim will ignore my alias for pdflatex (something like alias pdflatex='pdflatex --temp-dir=something'). Is it possible to make vim not ignore it?

Comment: Is it possible your vim shell or shelltype don't match your login shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vim 'ignores' your aliases because your shell is not in a 'mood' to parse your `.bash_profile/.bashrc` (you did not specify, where your aliases are defined) because it is not started as a login/interactive shell (read [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) to find out more about what is read when and for what reason).

So, you have several options:

1. Put the code you use in your `pdflatex` alias into a script and call that
2. vimrc: `'set shell=/bin/bash\ -l'`, put your aliases to .bash_profile
3. Call your shell as an interactive/login shell:   `:! bash -l -i -e 'pdflatex .'`

Comment: Login/non-login doesn't matter for `~/.bashrc` - only interactive/non-interactive does.

Comment: my aliases are in .bash_profile.. hmm I changed the question a little. I'd rather it run in the current shell. Your second solution seemed the most 'acceptable' however, it makes the % variable useless since opening a new shell usually starts at the home folder.

Comment: This is an amazing and thorough answer.  Thanks!

Comment: `set shell=/bin/bash\ -li` in .vimrc did the trick.  works fine on mac sierra. did not have to copy or move aliases at all thx!